# Minecraft Bedrock edition on multiple devices

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can I create a Minecraft Bedrock edition world on my Switch and continue to play it on Windows 10?

I can create a realm and sign into it from both but I’d just like to have a single player world.

I was even able to use it as a single player world but only by uploading it onto a realm in one device and then downloading the world on another device. But that’s not ideal :-(

Comment: I heard that such a feature exists in MCBE, but I think it's disabled on some devices, mainly because some console companies are extremely paranoid about anything involving the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single player worlds cannot be transferred between consoles and desktop. It's not as much of a matter that they're incompatible as much as the Switch does not allow file access to the worlds.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using a realm to transfer it. If you don't mind paying for the service, just keep the world on the realm, and then the world is forever synced across devices. While not ideal since it costs real money, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

In Bedrock Edition, there are 2 forms of accessing your worlds: External and Application.

If you are using External worlds, you can dig further in your files and access them. It's a good way to copy-paste your world into your PC if you can plug in your device via a wire or USB.

> All my worlds are from the Application so its saved only on my phone, so I can't really demonstrate it via photos.